# Python: Avoid Nested loop conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could someone tell me how can I reduce the nested for loops and if conditions from the below python code, so that it will become less complex. As of now, I am unable to break this code further, hence need help.

```py
checks = {
    "datasource_path": "customer/",
    "checks": [
        {
            "type": "check1",
            "kwargs": {"file_path": "cars/", "file_format": "orc"},
        },
        {"type": "check2", "kwargs": {"table": "cars/"}},
    ],
}

special_checks = {"check1", "check2", "check3"}

outcomes = []

for check in checks:
    check_type = check.get("type")
    if check_type is None or check_type not in special_checks:
        continue 
    keyword_args = check.get("kwargs")
    table_path = keyword_args.get("table")
    if keyword_args is None or table_path is None:
        continue
    path = table_path
    try:
        dataframe_dict[path] = table_path

        for key in get_check_class_from_name(
            check_type
        ).get_check_arguments():
            if "column" in key and keyword_args.get(key) is not None:
                column_dict[path] = column_dict.get(path, set()).union(
                    {keyword_args[key]}
                    if isinstance(keyword_args[key], str)
                    else set(keyword_args[key])
                )
    except RuntimeError as error:
        outcomes.append((True, str(error)))

return outcomes, dataframe_dict, column_dict
```

Comment: Deeply nested code can be broken out into its own function.

Comment: Could you also describe in words, what the goal of that piece of code is? Maybe there are some alternative solutions, for example recursion that could work.

Comment: @andrew- can you please create functions so that I'll understand?

Comment: Functions are very basic to python so I think it better to point you to a tutorial https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/#functions-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to optimize your code without clearly knowing what the intention of it is. However, here are some general approaches to writing neat and less complex code.

Your if-cases can be a lot more readable by either declaring a function for them or using a variable to state what it means, like

```
def is_check_valid():
    # Do something
    return is_check_valid
if not is_check_valid():

or

is_check_valid = check_type is None or check_type not in special_checks
if not is_check_valid:

instead of

if check_type is None or check_type not in special_checks:
```

That way you will make it clear what the intent is of the statement.

Also you could try to create functions for some logic, in the same way as with the if-statements your intent will be a lot clearer and the flow of your code will be much more readable.

Comment: Thanks edvin. Let me give it a try and see if the cognitive complexity issue gets resolved

Answer (score 0):

Please consider sorting sequences and joining them with `itertools.groupby()` or just a generator:

```py
def join(seq1, key1, seq2, key2):
    iter1, iter2 = iter(sorted(seq1, key=key1)), iter(sorted(seq2, key=key2))
    try:
        l, r = next(iter1), next(iter2)
        while True:
            kl, jr = key1(l), key2(r)
            while kl < kr:
                l = next(iter1)
                kl = key1(l)
            while l > r:
                r = next(iter2)
                kr = key2(r)
            yield l, r
    
    except StopIteration:
        pass

merged = join(
    special_checks, lambda x: x, 
    checks, lambda check: check.get('type'),
)

for check, special in merged:
    ...
```

So that, you'll be able to do `max(n, m)*log(max(n, m))` passes instead of `m*n`

Comment: I am not able to understand anything. It has lot of nested while loops too.